# why gsva in R is not same as ssgsea in python?

Tags: python, r

in R
`ssGSEA.Score <- gsva(expr, Stem.Sets, kcdf="Gaussian", method = "ssgsea")` 
in python

```
sample_ssgsea = gp.ssgsea(
              data=expr_ZScore,
              gene_sets="gene_sets.gmt",
              min_size=5,
              max_size=1000,
              sample_norm_method='custom', # choose 'custom' will only use the raw value of `data`
              verbose=False)
```

May I ask why there is a significant difference between the enrichment scores obtained by using the method ssgsea in GSVA in R and the ssGSEA function in the gseapy package in Python?

data in python uses the same normalization method as the GSVA function in R

data in python uses the same normalization method as the GSVA function in R